# jQuery - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery

I am reading rows from a mySQL table and returning them to jQuery to display (using HTML, bootstrap) for the user to enter a value against. When the value is updated by the user the action is capture by jQuery and the value is returned to be updated in the table (so I need the row's key in order to update the correct row).

So the user can not change the key, and have a different (wrong) row updated in the table, I am encrypting the row keys before sending them to the jQuery. I use the row's key as the id for each HTML line so each has a unique id and I know which has been update.

```
//Loop for each encoded_task_detail_ID
String summer = "ta" + encoded_task_detail_ID;
<textarea class='summernote col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' id="+ summer +" name='ymSpecificLine' rows='1'>
//end loop
```

Some rows are name='ymSpecificLine' and some are not. So in the jQuery I check:

```
var taKey = "#ta" + val_awardDetailID;

var val_ymSpecific = "N";
var val_ymSpecificLine = "";
alert("1");
if ($(taKey).attr('name') === "ymSpecificLine"){ //I have tried == here as well
    alert("2"); //Not displayed when error occurs
    val_ymSpecific = "Y";
    val_ymSpecificLine = $(taKey).val();
};
```

If the key (val_awardDetailID - same as encoded_task_detail_ID) is "Nzly" then this works. However, when the key is "MjM5MQ==" then there is a console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #taMjM5MQ==
```

I thought it may have something to do with it ending in "==" so I added an "A" to give "#taMjM5MQ==A". However the same error was returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `\\=\\=` instead of `==`, which escaped character `=`. Like: `#taMjM5MQ\\=\\=A`

And to replace that by code:
`taKey = taKey.split('=').join('\\=')`
While this is not very effeciency there're many better 'replaceAll' implementations on the internet.

(Sorry for not being online for 2 days)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors work similar to CSS selectors. `#taMjM5MQ==` is not a valid selector.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/reddysridhar53/hzycv82d/2/

Comment: Thank you. Is there a solution for this as I have this throughout my application and so is going to be a lot of work to correct.

Comment: Your keys are base 64 encoded I guess so you can decode using `atob()` and use `var summer = "ta" + atob(encoded_task_detail_ID)`

Comment: use `\\=\\=` instead of `==`, which escaped character `=`. Like: `#taMjM5MQ\\=\\=A`

Comment: @MeowCat2012 - Each val_awardDetailID is different. How do I check the val_awardDetailID before using it and add the escape characters please?

Comment: sridhar reddy - this works; however, the changes to the system are far more extensive than if I can escape the characters. So the solution from @MeowCat2012 is my preferred if I can work out how to apply it.

Comment: @MeowCat2012 - I found the answer "taKey = taKey.replace(/\=/g, '\\=')". Please move your answer to the Answer so I can accept it. A big thank you to sridhar reddy also for you good answer.